# Is there a way to verify a Python interpreter built from source is correct?

Tags: python, linux, cross-compiling, regression

For my embedded project I'm using BusyBox which builds Python 2.7 from source for the ARMHF architecture.  Is there any existing set of regression tests I can run on the target to ensure the built Python binary is correct?

Comment: Correct in which terms?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/devguide/runtests.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [dev guide](https://docs.python.org/devguide/runtests.html):

```
./python -m test
```

or

```
./python -m test -j3
```